# Marker customization and direction API

Tags: json, web-services, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps to display direction in my application. I would like to customize the markers to display more text than the default which shows only the position name i.e the city,state and in others zip code. My idea is to add customized text on the marker bubble. Here is my code in what I have tried so far. 
Note: I have tried to add markers but are not working. And also data to populate the map is obtained using json from db. I have posted sample result after the code.

Code:

```
  var directionDisplay;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var map;

  function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom:7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: chicago
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  }

  function calcRoute() {
     // get route no
     var request='';
     var route_no=($(".route_no").attr('id')); 
     $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: base_url+"index.php/routes/getMapData",
         data: {
            route: route_no
         },
         success: function(data){
             //alert(JSON.stringify(data[0].waypoints))
             var datavalues='';
             datavalues=data[0];
             var wypt=[];

                    $.each(datavalues.waypoints,function(index,value){
                    {
                      wypt.push({location: value.location,stopover: value.stopover})

                    }
                });



             request={

                 origin:""+data[0].origin+"",
                 destination:""+data[0].destination+"",
                   waypoints:  wypt,
                 travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
             }
        //Add marker
        var mark=[]; 
                $.each(datavalues.title,function(index,value){
                    mark.push({location:value.location,title: value.company})
                });

               var marker= new google.maps.Marker( mark );
                marker.setMap(map);
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
             return false;
         },
         dataType: 'json'         
     })

  }
```

Sample JSON result:

```
[{"origin":"Mantachie MS 38855","destination":"Mantachie MS 38855","waypoints":[{"stopover":true,"location":"JACKSON TN 38305"},{"stopover":true,"location":"UPPER SANDUSKY ON 43351"}],"title":[{"company":"TBMS","location":"Mantachie MS 38855"},{"company":"ARJ MANUFACTURING","location":"JACKSON TN 38305"},{"company":"BRIDGESTONE","location":"UPPER SANDUSKY ON 43351"},{"company":"TBMS","location":"Mantachie MS 38855"}]}]
```

I would like to display the company names on the markers too alongside the city and states.

[Here is a sample map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple) by google showing how the direction API work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example which customizes the icon, the text in the infowindow and adds an entry to the sidebar: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_custom_iconsC.html

**code snippet:**

```js
// this variable will collect the html which will eventually be placed in the side_bar 
      var side_bar_html = "";

      var gmarkers = [];
      var map = null;
      var startLocation = null;
      var endLocation = null;

      function initialize() {
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(24.7756, 121.0062);

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
          center: center,
          zoom: 13,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.close();
        });

        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var request = {
          origin: "532 Beacon St., Boston, MA",
          destination: "77 Massachusetts Ave, Cambridge, MA",
          travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
        };

        var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: [],
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeWeight: 3
        });

        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var route = response.routes[0];
            var summaryPanel = document.getElementById("directions_panel");
            var detailsPanel = document.getElementById("direction_details");
            startLocation = new Object();
            endLocation = new Object();

            summaryPanel.innerHTML = "";
            detailsPanel.innerHTML = '<ul>';

            // For each route, display summary information.
            for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
              var routeSegment = i + 1;
              summaryPanel.innerHTML += "<b>Route Segment: " + routeSegment + "</b><br />";
              summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + " to ";
              summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + "<br />";
              summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + "<br /><br />";
            }
            var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
            var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
            for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
              if (i == 0) {
                startLocation.latlng = legs[i].start_location;
                startLocation.address = legs[i].start_address;
                createMarker(legs[i].start_location, "start", legs[i].start_address, "green");
              }
              endLocation.latlng = legs[i].end_location;
              endLocation.address = legs[i].end_address;
              var steps = legs[i].steps;
              for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
                var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
                detailsPanel.innerHTML += "<li>" + steps[j].instructions;
                var dist_dur = "";
                if (steps[j].distance && steps[j].distance.text) dist_dur += "&nbsp;" + steps[j].distance.text;
                if (steps[j].duration && steps[j].duration.text) dist_dur += "&nbsp;" + steps[j].duration.text;
                if (dist_dur != "") {
                  detailsPanel.innerHTML += "(" + dist_dur + ")<br /></li>";
                } else {
                  detailsPanel.innerHTML += "</li>";

                }
                for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
                  polyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
                  bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);



                }
              }
            }

            detailsPanel.innerHTML += "</ul>"
            polyline.setMap(map);
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            createMarker(endLocation.latlng, "end", endLocation.address, "red");
            // == create the initial sidebar ==
            makeSidebar();

          }
        });
      }
      var icons = new Array();
      icons["red"] = {
        url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png",
        // This marker is 32 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
        size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
        // The origin for this image is 0,0.
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        // The anchor for this image is at 16,32.
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 32)
      };

      function getMarkerImage(iconColor) {
          if ((typeof(iconColor) == "undefined") || (iconColor == null)) {
            iconColor = "red";
          }
          if (!icons[iconColor]) {
            icons[iconColor] = {
              url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/" + iconColor + ".png",
              // This marker is 32 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
              size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
              // The origin for this image is 0,0.
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              // The anchor for this image is at 16,32.
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 32)
            };
          }
          return icons[iconColor];

        }
        // Marker sizes are expressed as a Size of X,Y
        // where the origin of the image (0,0) is located
        // in the top left of the image.

       // Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker
       // increase in the X direction to the right and in
       // the Y direction down.

      var iconImage = {
        url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png',
        // This marker is 32 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
        size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
        // The origin for this image is 0,0.
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        // The anchor for this image is at 16,32.
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 32)
      };
       // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon.
       // The type defines an HTML &lt;area&gt; element 'poly' which
       // traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points. The final
       // coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first
       // coordinate.
      var iconShape = {
        coord: [9, 0, 6, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 0, 8, 0, 12, 1, 14, 2, 16, 5, 19, 7, 23, 8, 26, 9, 30, 9, 34, 11, 34, 11, 30, 12, 26, 13, 24, 14, 21, 16, 18, 18, 16, 20, 12, 20, 8, 18, 4, 16, 2, 15, 1, 13, 0],
        type: 'poly'
      };
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
      });

      function createMarker(latlng, label, html, color) {
        // alert("createMarker("+latlng+","+label+","+html+","+color+")");
        var contentString = '<b>' + label + '</b><br>' + html;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latlng,
          map: map,
          icon: getMarkerImage(color),
          shape: iconShape,
          title: label,
          zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
        });
        marker.myname = label;
        gmarkers.push(marker);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.setContent(contentString);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
      }

      function myclick(i) {
          google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
        }
        // == rebuilds the sidebar to match the markers currently displayed ==

      function makeSidebar() {
        var html = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
          html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')">' + gmarkers[i].myname + '<\/a><br>';
        }
        document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = html;
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="float:left;width:70%;height:100%;"></div>
<div id="control_panel" style="float:right;width:30%;text-align:left;padding-top:20px">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="directions_panel" style="margin:20px;background-color:#FFEE77;"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="direction_details" style="margin:20px;"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="side_bar" style="margin:20px;"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```