# customize source and destination icons in google maps api

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps JavaScript API v3 and I want to show direction on the map by giving start and end points. when I draw the direction google automatically sets its default icons for source and destination. Is there any way to remove those icons and I use my own marker icon? I couldn't find it in google documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Marker customization and direction API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152357/marker-customization-and-direction-api)

Answer (score 0):

You can use option

```
suppressMarkers: true
```

see Google Maps API [docs for DirectionsRenderer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#DirectionsRenderer). And then create your markers at start and end point.